# Setting LayoutTransform to RotateTransform for elements on a Canvas yields unexpected results

Tags: c#, wpf

From within MainWindow ctor :

```
for(var i = 0; i <5; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button {};
            button.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(i * 10);
            button.Width = 300;
            button.Height = 300;
            TempCanvas.Children.Add(button);

        }
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Please can someone explain why this is happening.  I am expecting the 5 buttons to be rotated through the same point.

I did not want to RenderTransform as the graphics that I will be rendering would be drawn outside of the parent and not reflected in the measure.

Comment: Because it's layout transform, it has to fit in the canvas, so instead of going outside, it translates until it fits. I think. Not completely sure. But using a RenderTransform and shifting your objects manually (Position before applying transform) should fix it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx
Might be the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Skami - that property does not apply to a layout transform

Comment: _" I am expecting the 5 buttons to be rotated through the same point"_ -- which same point? Please be precise as to exactly what output you want. There are lots of possibilities that still meet "the same point" criteria (an infinite number, in fact). Are you even still looking for an answer? If not, you should accept the answer that best responded to your question. If so, please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a precise description of what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Canvas is the issue, unlike other contains it is not constrained in its physical size, it stretches out to infinity in all directions. Therefore it's rotation origin is not the canvas.width/2 by canvas.height/2.

If you repeat your code in a grid or dockpanel you will get the required result.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: This answer is not quite right. In particular, other types of container controls don't automatically put the rotation original at {width/2,height/2} either, but they _do_ (unlike `Canvas`) perform additional layout which may involve stretching and centering child objects. That additional layout can tend to make moot differences in transformation settings, as they apply their own transforms after the fact. It almost certainly is the case the OP can get this to work with `Canvas`, but they will need to provide more details for someone to answer that specifically.

Comment: Learn something new everyday :) Cheers Peter

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

[image: Render trnas]

***Code:***

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button { };
            //button.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(i * 10);
            button.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(i * 10);
            button.Width = 300;
            button.Height = 300;
            button.Margin = new Thickness(200, 0, 0, 0);
            TempCanvas.Children.Add(button);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Kylo but no.  I wanted to use a LayoutTransform.